# How to get the map canvas CRS in EPSG code?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

This is probably a simple request but I cannot find a way around it:

**how can I read from python the map canvas CRS?**

I know how to set it up:

```
canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.mapRenderer().setProjectionsEnabled(True)
canvas.mapRenderer().setDestinationCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(EPSG_CODE))
```

But I want to do that ONLY if I need it:

```
canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
canCRS = (????)
wgsCRS = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)
bBox = canvas.extent()

if canCRS == wgsCRS:
  # get get lat long of canvas extent
  lon = bBox.xMinimum()
  lat = bBox.yMinimum()
  lonMax = bBox.xMaximum()
  latMax = bBox.yMaximum()

  return lon, lat, lonMax, latMax

else:
  # set map canvas CRS and get lat long of the extent
  canvas.mapRenderer().setProjectionsEnabled(True)
  canvas.mapRenderer().setDestinationCrs(wgsCRS)
  lon = bBox.xMinimum()
  lat = bBox.yMinimum()
  lonMax = bBox.xMaximum()
  latMax = bBox.yMaximum()

  return lon, lat, lonMax, latMax
```

How do I get the map canvas CRS in EPSG code so I can compare it with QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)? Which method should I use?

Comment: The first axis (x) of EPSG:4326 is lat not lon ~ https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
canvas.mapRenderer().destinationCrs().authid()
```

That will return the map canvases' current crs as an epsg code

Comment: Yes, thanks @ndawson, that did it! The only thing that needs to be change is the comparison in canCRS == wgsCRS..authid()

Answer (score 21):

In QGIS3 API changed:

```
iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().destinationCrs().authid()
'EPSG:3045'
```

Comment: `QgsProject.instance().crs().authid()` also works.